# Bootstrap 4 – Disable tabs function on mobile devices

Tags: bootstrap-4

I use standard Bootstrap 4 tabs and want the tabs to get "untabbed" on mobile devices. "Untabbed" means

1. remove the navigation tabs and
2. show all tab contents among each other.

```html
<div class="container">

  <ul class="nav nav-justified nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Tab 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Tab 2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">Tab 3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">Tab content 1</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">Tab content 2</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">Tab content 3</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

What I want to achieve

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `d-none d-sm-flex` classes on the below div and add the style shown below.

```
  <ul class="nav nav-justified nav-tabs d-none d-sm-flex" id="myTab" role="tablist">
```

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 575px) {
  .tab-content>.tab-pane {
    display: block !important;
    opacity: 1 !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="container">

  <ul class="nav nav-justified nav-tabs d-none d-sm-flex" id="myTab" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Tab 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Tab 2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">Tab 3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">Tab content 1</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">Tab content 2</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">Tab content 3</div>
  </div>

</div>
```